# JavaScript to JQuery; formatting date for MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker, datetime-format

So after trial and error, I've finally got my calendar running the way I'd like. I have it only allowing a certain time slot to be selected. It's anywhere from 10 to 21 days from whatever the current date is. However, I'm plugging this new calendar into a slot where another calendar preexisted and I need to ensure that the values get passed into MySQL correctly, based off how it was previously set up.

The code that existed previously was JavaScript and I changed it over to JQuery. The previous code had this line in it:

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' // MySQL datetime format
```

Now, I'd like the same date format for my new calendar if possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.txtDeadline').datepicker({ minDate: +10, maxDate: +21 });
  });


// Still needs dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' for MySQL datetime format
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>



<div class="clear">
 <label for="txtDeadline">Deadline<span class="required">*</span></label>
 <div class="input">
  <input class="txtDeadline" name="txtDeadline" type="text" />
  <p>Min: 10 days Max: 21 days from current date</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.txtDeadline').datepicker({ minDate: +10, maxDate: +21,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  });


// Still needs dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' for MySQL datetime format
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>



<div class="clear">
 <label for="txtDeadline">Deadline<span class="required">*</span></label>
 <div class="input">
  <input class="txtDeadline" name="txtDeadline" type="text" />
  <p>Min: 10 days Max: 21 days from current date</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: my pleasure to help you